# Why do I get linear model when I tried to fit exponential model?

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, exponential-smoothing, nls

I was wondering why do I get linear model when I'm using exponential model,
`y = a * exp(-b*-x)`, to fit my data.

Here is my code:

```
ff <- function(x,a,b){a * exp(-b*-x)}
fit2 <- nls(y ~ ff(x,a,b) , data = newdat, start =c(a=107.4623,b=-0.0037)
```

The graph below is mydata with the exponential fit (prediction of `fit2`) in purple curve. The green curve is what I though it would be, it is `Smooth.splines` fit.
[image]

Result from `fit2`:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: dif2 ~ ff(age, a, b)
   data: newdat
         a          b 
109.743680  -0.003793 
 residual sum-of-squares: 2585

Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.446e-06
```

[image]
Here is my data:

```
   ID  x   y
    1 18 106.47
    1 19 100.35
    1 20 97.4
    1 21 101.03
    1 22 100.3
    1 23 99.06
    1 24 100.81
    2 18 101.95
    2 19 100.69
    2 20 100.89
    3 14 105.87
    3 15 107.44
    3 16 103.05
    3 17 104.86
    3 18 101.86
    3 19 101.48
    3 20 102.77
    3 21 99.63
    3 22 100.21
    3 23 101.28
    3 24 98.77
    3 25 99.91
    4 17 102.42
    4 18 101.85
    4 19 101.31
    5 18 101.24
    5 19 102.27
    5 20 100.03
    5 21 101.53
    6 20 98.08
    6 21 101.2
    6 22 103.16
    6 23 98.3
    6 24 102.21
    6 25 100.18
    6 27 95.28
    6 28 102.05
    6 29 100.72
    6 30 101.4
    7 13 111.3
    7 14 106.55
    7 15 103.23
    7 16 102.31
    7 17 101.11
    7 18 101.52
    7 19 100.14
    8 18 101.05
    8 19 98.15
    8 20 100.55
    8 21 101.62
    8 22 101.04
    8 23 98.22
    9 18 102.87
    9 19 101.46
    9 20 101.07
    9 21 101.32
    10 20 101.93
    10 21 101.73
    10 22 100.24
    11 19 99.75
    11 20 101.35
    11 21 99.34
    11 22 100.12
    12 18 103.34
    12 19 109.52
    12 20 106.98
    12 21 105.21
    12 22 98.87
    12 23 103.81
    12 24 100.38
    12 25 100.12
    12 26 99.7
    12 27 101.16
    12 28 99.02
    12 29 100.15
    12 30 97.32
    13 13 116.43
    13 14 111.75
    13 15 107.42
    13 16 103.5
    13 17 103.37
    13 18 100.66
    13 19 100.73
    13 20 100.84
    13 21 100.05
    14 18 101.66
    14 19 99.9
    14 20 101.4
    14 21 99.86
    14 22 100.82
    15 15 101.27
    15 16 100.01
    15 17 104.27
    16 19 100.26
    16 20 104.13
    17 18 106.12
    18 21 101.18
    18 22 99.51
    18 23 100.59
    19 18 100
    19 19 100.81
    19 20 99.37
    19 21 102.6
    20 22 102.18
    20 23 104.5
    20 24 100.74
    21 22 103.74
    21 23 98.66
    21 24 100.65
    21 25 99.63
    22 24 102.59
    22 25 94.62
    22 26 103.85
    23 20 100.7
    23 21 101.38
    23 22 102.36
    23 23 99.56
    23 24 100
    24 18 101.16
    24 19 99.64
    25 21 96.9
    25 22 109.3
    25 23 101.4
    25 24 98.04
    25 25 99.28
    25 26 99.63
    25 27 101.29
    25 28 100.08
    26 14 109
    26 15 112.37
    26 16 102.4
    26 17 102.15
    26 18 100.82
    27 18 101.14
    27 19 101.38
    28 17 105.09
    28 18 101.74
    28 19 100.2
    29 19 102.11
    29 20 100.57
    29 21 100.91
    29 22 99.61
    29 23 99.99
    30 18 99.81
    30 19 102.07
    31 19 100.75
    31 21 95.43
    32 23 99.73
    32 24 100.8
    32 25 100.1
    32 26 100.88
    32 27 97.73
    32 28 100.36
    33 22 99.4
    33 24 101.46
    33 18 97.65
    33 25 102.75
    33 26 97.7
    33 27 100.67
    34 21 98.27
    34 22 100.42
    34 23 101.16
    34 24 100.13
    34 25 98.55
    35 17 107.46
    35 18 100.22
    35 19 102.03
    35 20 101.52
    35 21 102.05
    35 22 102.46
    35 23 101.56
    35 24 96.88
    35 25 98.97
    35 26 101.68
    35 28 94.12
    36 20 98.63
    36 21 101.59
    36 22 98.76
    37 19 101.9
    37 20 98.66
    37 21 100.19
    37 22 100.03
    37 23 99.97
    38 15 104.32
    38 16 102.98
    38 17 103.4
    38 18 102.78
    38 19 101.73
    38 20 95.57
    39 22 101.5
    39 23 98.37
    39 24 100.4
    39 25 100.79
    40 19 102.93
    40 20 100.88
    40 21 99
    40 22 99.66
    41 21 107.08
    41 22 93.08
    41 24 100.91
    41 25 107.24
    41 26 99.8
    42 14 109.82
    42 15 106.09
    42 16 106.32
    42 17 102.8
    42 18 100.21
    42 19 102.08
    42 21 99.22
    42 22 100.13
    42 23 101.63
    43 16 100.95
    43 17 100.6
    43 18 101.81
    43 19 102.78
    43 20 98.43
    43 23 101.4
    43 24 103.12
    43 25 99.31
    43 26 100.47
    43 27 99.67
    43 28 98.75
    43 29 95.68
    44 23 103.78
    44 24 100.38
    44 25 99.39
    44 26 100.87
    44 27 99.64
    44 28 98.39
    44 29 97.62
    45 18 100.47
    45 19 101.41
    45 20 99.33
    45 21 101.08
    45 22 100.08
    45 23 100.22
    45 24 99.67
    45 25 100.45
    45 26 102.4
    45 27 95.7
    46 20 101.35
    46 21 98.73
    46 22 109.29
    46 23 100.04
    46 24 95.74
    46 25 100.44
    46 26 98.72
    47 19 100.51
    47 20 99.88
    47 21 101.7
    47 22 101.94
    47 23 100.72
    47 24 98.73
    47 25 102.16
    47 26 100.25
    47 27 95.1
    47 28 103.08
    48 25 105.21
    48 26 100.48
    48 27 98.07
    48 28 99.88
    48 29 95.61
    49 16 111.35
    49 17 92.43
    49 18 112.04
    49 19 100.8
    49 20 95.36
    49 21 103.13
    49 22 102.16
    49 23 98.81
    49 25 98.86
    49 26 99.93
    49 27 95.26
    50 23 98.15
    50 24 105.93
    50 25 99.01
    50 26 99.34
    50 27 93.68
    50 28 105.35
    51 24 100.96
    51 25 100.53
    51 26 99.2
    51 27 100.52
    51 28 100.86
    52 25 101.38
    52 26 98.45
    52 27 100.32
    52 28 99.24
    52 29 102.74
    53 24 101.37
    53 25 99.75
    53 27 96.31
    53 28 100.67
    54 22 98.09
    54 23 100.55
    54 24 100.25
    54 25 101.54
    54 26 98.48
    54 27 102.76
    54 28 98.5
    54 30 99.85
    55 22 103.87
    55 23 94.37
    55 24 105.12
    56 18 101.23
    56 19 99.26
    56 20 102.63
    56 21 100.75
    56 23 101.5
    56 24 99.14
    56 27 95.11
    57 16 107.57
    57 17 101.75
    57 18 107.18
    57 19 100.23
    57 20 105.48
    57 21 103.1
    57 22 100.45
    57 23 99.28
    57 24 100.52
    57 25 98.69
    58 27 103.13
    58 28 97.86
    58 29 101.33
    58 30 98.33
    58 32 102.14
    58 34 94.47
    58 35 98.29
    59 19 97.6
    59 20 98.93
    59 22 101.35
    59 23 93.88
    60 20 99.62
    60 22 97.36
    60 23 102.94
    60 24 98.98
    60 25 99.47
    61 18 100.15
    61 19 101.92
    61 20 101.34
    61 21 98.87
    61 22 97.68
    61 23 99.92
    61 24 100.78
    61 25 98.21
    62 20 102.7
    62 21 99.7
    62 22 100.17
    62 23 99.62
    62 24 100.59
```

Comment: I don't know R that well, so I cannot see whether your code is correct. But you should check what your parameter estimates are. Can you write them down for us?

Comment: What is (-b * -x)? Is it (-b*(-x)) = (b*x) ?

Comment: Yeah. It's the same thing. Lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say precisely why your loess fit differs from the exponential fit -- that's more less "because it does, because they're different" -- but the reason that your exponential fit looks so linear, and why it looks so different from your plotted function, is that *over the range of the data* it is very close to linear.  The parameter is -0.0037, the range of the data is about delta-x=20, so the curve only falls by about 7%.  For this range, the expansion $\exp(bx) = 1+bx + O((bx)^2)$ works pretty well.

**Update**: your original (slightly mangled) `nls` fit was $y=a \exp(bx)+d$, i.e. there was an additive term.  This makes all the difference:

```
dd <- read.table("expreg.dat",header=TRUE)
m0 <- nls(y~a*exp(b*x),dd,
          start=list(a=100,b=-0.1))
coef(m0)
##             a             b 
## 109.743701855  -0.003793346 

m1 <- nls(y~a*exp(b*x)+d,dd,
          start=list(a=100,b=-0.1,d=60))
coef(m1)
##            a            b            d 
## 1401.8573693   -0.3599526   99.7863827
```

For what it's worth, you can fit the model *without* the additive term using `glm(...,family=gaussian(link="log"))`, which is convenient for incorporating in `ggplot`s.

```
dd$pred <- predict(m1)
library("ggplot2"); theme_set(theme_bw())
g0 <- ggplot(dd,aes(x,y))+geom_point(aes(colour=factor(ID)))+
    geom_smooth(method="glm",family=gaussian(link="log"))+
        scale_colour_discrete(guide="none")
g2 <- g0 + geom_line(aes(y=pred),colour="red")
```

[image]

Now plot over a wider range:

```
g1 <- g0 + expand_limits(x=c(0,240),y=c(0,120))+
    geom_smooth(method="glm",family=gaussian(link="log"),
                fullrange=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you think transforming my response so that it has a larger range would make the fit looks more "exponential"? Also, what do you mean by this "For this range, the expansion exp(bx)=1+bx+O((bx)2) works pretty well."? Do you mean I could fit the model using this "1+bx+O((bx)2)" ?
Btw,Thanks for yours answer

Comment: see updates ...

Comment: That's look good!! Originally, I was trying to fit the model using a*exp(bx)+d, but I can't find the reasonable starting point for d. So, how did you find initial value for d?

Comment: Trial and error in this case. Eyeballing the data works too ...

Comment: One more thing, do you think (y~a*exp(b*x+c)+d), by adding "c", would be even better or it's just going to be too complex?

Comment: That model would be unidentifiable; it's equivalent to `y~a*\exp(c)*\exp(bx)+d`, so any combination of `a` and `\exp(c)` with the same product will have the same predictions ...

Answer (score 1):

```
ff <- function(x,a,b){a * exp(-b*-x)+d}
fit2 <- nls(y ~ ff(x,a,b) , data = newdat, start =c(a=107.4623,b=-0.0037)
```

In your function `d` is not defined! I had to remove `d` from the `ff` function, and I ended up estimating only `a` and `b`. In this way I obtained the following fit...

```
Formula: y ~ a * exp(-b * -x)

Parameters:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a 109.743724   0.924359  118.72   <2e-16 ***
b  -0.003793   0.000379  -10.01   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.725 on 348 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.105e-06
```

[image]

How can your code work if `d` is not defined inside the function `ff` and you are not passing it as argument?

Comment: It suppose to be a * exp(-b*-x).

Comment: The funny thing is we got the same estimate for 'a' and 'b' but out plot is totally different. Did you get your prediction by using 'predict(fit2)'? Anyway, both yours and mine doesn't look anything like exponential curve.

Comment: Yes! I used lines(predict(fit2), col = "purple") !

Comment: Hm. Interesting! The purple curve look like piece-wise function. I plot the equation with coefficient from your result in Google. It should be the same as mine.